# Redirecting to a different fragment once the timer is finished

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make the fragment automatically redirect to another fragment once the timer has run out. How would I go about doing that? Thanks

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000){
        override fun onFinish() {
            game_timer?.text = "Done"

        }

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            game_timer?.text = "" + millisUntilFinished / 1000
        }

    }.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using `androidx.navigation`. If your aren't, have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    object : CountDownTimer(30000, 1000){
        override fun onFinish() {
            game_timer?.text = "Done"

            activity.findNavController( R.id.your_nav_host_in_your_activity).navigate(R.id.your_target_fragment )
        }

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            game_timer?.text = "" + millisUntilFinished / 1000
        }

    }.start()
```

Comment: Yes using navigation, But they all work through buttons, and I'm trying to get it to navigate without on click

Comment: This should work, then if your time does. You'll need to change the `id`s of course, as I used placeholders.

Comment: what would I have to put in the onFinish() to get it to redirecT? currently only have it to display done

Comment: `activity.findNavController( R.id.your_nav_host_in_your_activity).navigate(R.id.your_target_fragment )` is the bit the does the redirect.